# Using GETDATE WITH DATEDIFF?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to find any HireDate more than 3 years before the current date but I'm confused about the syntax. Heres the problem

```
 IF DATEDIFF(year,HireDate,GETDATE) > 3
```

Comment: Use parentheses for `GETDATE`: `DATEDIFF(year,HireDate,GETDATE())`

Comment: Yes, that won't work, as it just looks at the year part of the date, so DATEDIFF(YEAR, '20161231', '20170101') will return an answer of 1.  You would be better to use MONTH then divide by 12, or DAY then divide by 365.

Comment: Read Gordon's answer....

Comment: I suggest the SELECT line from Pradeep Kumar Prabaharan's answer and the WHERE line from Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `DATEDIFF()`!  Use `DATEADD()`:

```
where HireDate < dateadd(year, -3, GETDATE())
```

`DATEDIFF()` does not do what you think it does.  It counts the number of year boundaries between two dates.  So, the difference between Jan 1 20015 and Dec 31 2016 is 1 year.

In addition, with `DATEDIFF()` the column is an argument to the function.  That prevents SQL Server from using an index on the column.  This is not a problem with `DATEADD()` because the argument is `GETDATE()`, not a column in a table.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
SELECT HireDate from table_name
WHERE DATEDIFF(Year, HireDate, GETDATE()) > 3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if DATEADD(year,3,HireDate)<GETDATE()
```

Comment: It's always better not to use functions on the column, so instead of this, the better way is `HireDate < dateadd(year, -3, getdate())` that way in case there is an index for HireDate, it can also be used.

Answer (score 2):

Once try this Query to resolve your issue.

SELECT Hiredate FROM TableName
WHERE  datediff(year,Hiredate ,getdate())>=3